# Azure Database and Photos

Tags: c#, image, azure

I have a database set up in Azure, and along with some other data types, it will house some pictures. The column to hold the photos is an Image data type. My insert looks like this (converts the pic to a binary file)

```
 public void Insert()    
    {
     string filepath = "C:\\PictureFolder\\MyPhoto.jpg";
     byte[] Pic = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

     DataContex oDc = new DataContex();

     tblShip otblShip = new tblShip;

     otblShip.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     otblShip.Name = "Enterprise";
     otblShip.Picture = Pic;

     oDc.tblShips.InsertOnSubmit(oMyTable);

     oDc.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

The insert works, when I check my table in Azure, a binary value is inserted in the Picture column. How do I get it back, and how do I display an actual photo in my WPF interface?

Comment: You should explore the possibility of storing your images in Blob storage and simply store its id or path in the database.  Storage cost is way cheaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @CSharpRocks that, since you're already using Azure, it'll be very convenient for you to do some research and store your pictures on a BlobStorage storage account. Storage accounts have many advantages when compared to traditional database storage.

You can find more about storage accounts and how to get started with it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account).

But this question is more about how do you retrieve the image and show it in your WPF application, as per you own question. So let's see:

You already have you image stored on your database, so you can fetch the related  `tblShip` entity, using the primary key value (or any other query):

**Assuming you have this somewhere in your xaml view:**

```
<Image Name="imgControl" ... />
```

**You could show your image like this:**

```
private void DisplayImageFromDb(Guid id)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        var item = context
            .tblShips
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (item == null)
            throw new Exception("Image could not be found!");

        //Convert the byte[] to a BitmapImage
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(item.Picture);
        img.BeginInit();
        img.StreamSource = ms;
        img.EndInit();

        //assign the image to the Source property of the Image Control.
        imgControl.Source = img;
    }
}
```

This will work ok, but It'll be better if you use a more WPF (MVVM) oriented way. So let's say you have you xaml view, but your are using MVVM. The Image control is therefore bound to a viewmodel property:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" 
       Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageConverter}}"/>
```

**In your view's resources you declare the converter:**

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <local:ByteArrayToImageConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

**Here is the implementation for the converter:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ByteArrayToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            //Convert the byte[] to a BitmapImage
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);
            img.BeginInit();
            img.StreamSource = ms;
            img.EndInit();

            return img;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a clean separation of concerns so your UI is who actually is showing the image and your viewmodel should only load it from the database and manipulate the domain entity:

Your viewmodel must declare ImageSource property used for binding:

```
private byte[] imageSource;
public byte[] ImageSource
{
    get { return imageSource; }
    set
    {
        imageSource = value;
        //must implement property changed notifications
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageSource"));
    }
}
```

After all this refactoring, the method in the viewmodel, that loads the image can be implemented like this:

```
private void DisplayImageFromDb(int id)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        var item = context
            .tblShips
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (item == null)
            throw new Exception("Image could not be found!");

        //Assign the property and let the binding do the work
        ImageSource = item.Picture;
    }
}
```

You'll certainly get the same result, but you now have a very well separated app that will allow to be more easily maintained as it evolves.

Hope this helps!

Comment: .AsNoTracking() gives a red squiggle, asks for assembly reference or directive. I added System.Data.Entity; System.Data.Linq; Still no go.

Comment: @Coolhand you can safely remove that line for this case. I've tested it using an EF DbContext while you appear to be using another kind of datacontext.

Comment: My DataContext is from my dbml. I don't know what EF DbContext is.

Comment: I deleted .AsNoTracking() and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything's hard coded here, but here is how I move a 100 x 100 pixel image 
to and from the Db. I do understand there are better ways to store images, but for my purposes, this works great!

```
     public void InsertPhotoToDb()
    {
        string filepath = "C:\\TFS\\Enterprise.jpg";
        byte[] Pic = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

        ArmadaDataContext oDc = new ArmadaDataContext();

        tblPictureTest otblPictureTest = new tblPictureTest();
        otblPictureTest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        otblPictureTest.FileName = "Enterprise";
        otblPictureTest.Photo = Pic;
        oDc.tblPictureTests.InsertOnSubmit(otblPictureTest);
        oDc.SubmitChanges();

        oDc = null;
    }   

    private void DisplayImageFromDb()
    {
        using (var oDc = new ArmadaDataContext())
        {
            var item = oDc
                .tblPictureTests
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileName == "Enterprise"); // Retrieves using the filename


            //   If retrieving using the GUID, use the line below instead.
            //   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Guid.Parse("58b44a51-0627-43fe-9563-983aebdcda3a"));


            if (item == null)
                throw new Exception("Image could not be found!");

            //Convert the byte[] to a BitmapImage
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(item.Photo.ToArray());
            img.BeginInit();
            img.StreamSource = ms;
            img.EndInit();

            //assign the image to the Source property of the Image box in the UI.
            imgPhoto.Source = img;
        }
    }
```